# Google appengine - objectify issue. Embedded Classes dosen't get updaded

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a "User" entity and a nested Embedded Class "Options" like the code snippet below. However, the change of value in the Options class does NOT always get updated when I change & save it after I running this code "OfyService.ofy().save().entity(user);"

Anyone aware of this issue ? anything change its related the @Cache annotation? Thanks.

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class User {
@Id Long id;
Options options;
...

    public static class Options {
        Boolean optNotification;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here. Post more of your code that saves/loads the entities. Make sure you understand the async future behavior and when the futures get flushed (transaction boundaries, end of the `ObjectifyFilter`, or when you call `now()`).

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I reviewed all the load and save actions. I found have two save within one http requeset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're running into a [known stale cache issue with Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/227).

The proposed workaround is to delete the cache entry by doing the following:

```
MemcacheServiceFactory
    .getMemcacheService(ObjectifyFactory.MEMCACHE_NAMESPACE)
    .delete(key.toWebSafeString());
```

Comment: This "stale cache issue" is simply that if you're using the low-level API and bypassing Objectify, the cache can go out of date. Which shouldn't surprise anyone. This SO question does not mention the low level API at all, so this is not likely to be related.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Clifford for asking me listing saves/loads because it help me realize I have two saves. i.e. the code ran "OfyService.ofy().save().entity(user);" *twice* in one http request. I have just removed the first save and the problem is gone now. Btw, I before I remove the first save I already tried using defer() for the both save but it doesn't solution which surprised me.